# Flow test and Accounts

Tags: corda

New to Corda and I am trying to run (debug) flow tests using the Corda Accounts in a Mock Network and get the following error :
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Corda service com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.services.KeyManagementBackedAccountService does not exist`

when trying to create a anew account, or anything else for that matter.  Is there something I am missing ? Any code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That service is under `com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.services` package, meaning it's part of the `accounts-workflows` CorDapp; so you must include that CorDapp in your mocked network so it gets installed on your mocked nodes:

```
// Setup network.
network = new MockNetwork(new MockNetworkParameters().withCordappsForAllNodes(ImmutableList.of(                
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts"),
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.workflows"),
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.money"),
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection"),
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts"),
        // This CorDapp has the missing service from your error message.
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows"),
        TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.r3.corda.lib.ci")))
```

In general, if your node is supposed to run some code, you must install that code on that node; otherwise how it will be able to run it? So if you're using some library (e.g Accounts library, Tokens SDK); then you must install it on your node.